# Converting points between view coordinate systems

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I'm having a difficult time understanding the difference between `convert(_:to:)` and `convert(_:from:)` for some reason.

Let's say I have two views (`superView` and `subview`) and a root view:

```swift
let superView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 25, y: 25), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)))
rootView.addSubview(view)

let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 25, y: 25), size: .init(width: 50, height: 50)))
superView.addSubview(subview)
```

`convert(_:to:)` converts a point from the receiver’s coordinate system to that of the specified view, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622424-convert):

```swift
let convertToWindow = subview.convert(subview.bounds, to: window)
// {x 50 y 50 w 50 h 50 }
```

`convert(_:from:)` converts a point from the coordinate system of a given view to that of the receiver, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622424-convert):

```swift
let convertFromWindow = subview.convert(subview.bounds, from: window)
// {x -50 y -50 w 50 h 50 }
```

Is the "receiver" `subview` in this case? If so, I think I sort of understand `convert(_:from:)` to be converting `subview`'s coordinates with respect to is own coordinates (and not its super view) to the position within `window`, which is why it's going from `{x 0 y 0 w 50 h 50 }` to `{x 50 y 50 w 50 h 50 }`.

However, what is `convert(_:from:)` doing when it's converting `subviews.bound` that *already* uses the coordinate system of `subview`? Why doesn't `subview.convert(subview.bounds, from: window)` return `{x 0 y 0 w 50 h 50 }`?

Finally, if the `convert` method merely converts a point or a bound to and from a view, why does the instance the method belongs to make a difference in the result of the conversion?  For example, `subview.convert(subview.bounds, to: window)` and `superView.convert(subview.bounds, to: window)` yield different results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in an expression like `subview.convert...`, we call `subview` the "receiver" — it is the object to which the `convert` message is sent, so it *receives* that message.

> Why doesn't `subview.convert(subview.bounds, from: window)` return `{x 0 y 0 w 50 h 50 }`?

The mental mistake you're making here is that you think `subview.bounds` somehow pins this value to `subview`. It doesn't. The first parameter is merely *some numbers*. The `convert` method doesn't know where you got those numbers from. That is why you have to *tell* it where you got them — with the second parameter:

- If you say `from:`, you are saying, "I got these numbers from the second parameter's coordinate system".
- If you say `to:`, you are saying, "I got these numbers from the receiver's coordinate system".

> why does the instance the method belongs to make a difference in the result of the conversion

Because that is the other view in the story:

- If you say `to:`, you are saying, "I got these numbers *from* the receiver's coordinate system, and I want you to convert them *to* the second parameter's coordinate system."
- If you say `from:`, you are saying, "I got these numbers *from* the second parameter's coordinate system, and I want you to convert them *to* the receiver's coordinate system."

Remember, the *first* parameter is *just some numbers*. You can get them from anywhere you want, including the inside of your head, but you won't get the "right" answer if you lie about this in the rest of the expression — as some of your examples do.

Answer (score 1):

The "receiver" is indeed the object on which you make the call.

The name of the method should be understood looking from the perspective of this "receiver":

- 'to'-method: Coming from the receiver, what would the rectangle be when going **to** the view given as parameter.
- 'from'-method: Going towards the receiver, what would the rectangle be when coming **from** the view given as parameter.

In other words:

- With the 'to'-method you go **to** the other view.
- With the 'from'-method you come back **from** the other view.

Try to visualise it as traveling between the receiver view and the parameter view. You (i.e. the receiver) can go **to**, and come back **from** the parameter view.

I hope this helps.